# How to change textView width after animation?

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I have a fragment with just a text view in it.
At one Point in my app I want to rotate the fragment 90 degrees and translate it to one corner of my device screen. That works fine. The Problem now is that the width of the textview should change now. Before it was the width of the device now it should be the higth. So what I did is that I calculated both values and set the layout width like this:

```
LayoutParams params = fragment.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = text.getHeight();
        params.width = deviceHeight;
        fragment.setLayoutParams(params);
```

now the height is being displayed correct but the width not.
Instead the width doesn´t change. Even when I set the width to a random value (like 500) it doesn´t change...

Is this because of the animation? Why can´t I change the width of my textView?

EDIT:

My text views width is wrap_content so does that have anything to do with my problem?

Comment: Have you tried using `requestLayout` after changing the layout params?

Comment: @Kevin thanks for your reply! I didn´t but it doesn´t change anything.

Comment: what is "deviceHeight"

Comment: @TejjD the device height that I calculated but I tried other values aswell...

Comment: I've posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want the width of the `TextView` to change.

You are getting the `layoutParams()` of the Fragment, which means that the width and height you are setting are for the Fragment, and **NOT** for the view in question.

This is not ideal. I do agree that ViewGroups do have a [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html). You are firstly getting the `layoutParams()` of the Fragment and **NOT** the TextView. Change that as follows:

```
LayoutParams params = textView.getLayoutParams();
```

If that does not work, this will;

You need to get the view, and [set the width of that](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setWidth(int)), as and when you require:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
textView.setWidth(<the_width>;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but that is not the problem. I tried this a houndred times + I still have to rezise the fragment because else the textView is larger than the fragment.